# Error: Unexpected data declaration statement AND symbol has no IMPLICIT type

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm an amateur in Fortran. I met a strange error when immitating youtube tutorial of `FORTRAN in 100 Seconds` to write a simple program:

```
1 program myApp
2 implicit none
3     integer :: jeff
4     jeff = 23
5     print *, jeff
6     real :: c
7     read (*,*) c
8 end program myApp
```

Error message:

```
.\app4.f90:6:13:

     real :: c
             1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
.\app4.f90:7:16:

     read (*,*) c
                1
Error: Symbol 'c' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I searched by Google and GPT but only to be told to declare `c` before using it while this actually had been done by me.

I'm using Vscode and my gfortran compiler's version is 6.3.0.

During my debugging, I find that if I delete the 6-7th lines about `c`, the compilation would pass. Or even if I delete the 3-5th lines about `jeff`, the compilation would also pass. Or if I modify the 3-5th lines into `integer :: jeff = 23` the compilation would still pass. I can't understand what's the problem here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot put declarations like `real :: c` after executable statements. All declarations must be at the top. The duplicate is actually the first google hit for "Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)" for me. Also, do not just search Google, search also Stack Overflow for the error message, even if using Google.

Comment: Thanks! I got that I'm declaring at the wrong place. I had glanced at the duplicate before but he was declaring an array so I skipped. I'm sorry for not checking that carefully, thank you for informing me.